# PostgreSQL Create function return value of TIMESTAMP

Tags: postgresql

Have Table

```
CREATE TABLE datasource(
   trans varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   request_msg text NULL
   create_by varchar(10) NULL,
   create_date timestamp NULL
)
```

i need to create function and get data create_date by finding word in request_msg like 'xxx@mail.com'

```
create or replace function get_transaction_date(keyword text)
return TIMESTAMP as $$

begin
return query 
select
   tl.create_date
from
   datasource t1
where 
   t1.request_msg like '%' || keyword || '%'
   order by trans asc limit 1;

end; $$

language 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Explain “ get data create_date by finding word in request_msg like 'xxx@mail.com'”.

Comment: I add function but is not work

Comment: You need a single timestamp, or a list of timestamps?

Comment: Also what is your question?

Comment: i need single timestamp.

Comment: "*It does not work*" is not a valid error message in Postgres. What exactly doesn't work? What is the **exact** error message you get? If you get wrong results, then which results do you get and which one did you expect?

Comment: i need new function. The Function get create_date from table datasource

Comment: Please see [ask]. That will show the minimum the community expects to properly answer your question. In this particular question: post sample data - as text **no images** - the expected output from that date and the ***exact results*** you are currently getting.